# how many writes per day standard quota

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

1. How many batch writes or single writes in 24 hrs for a standard limits quota can firestore perform, after which it starts rejecting write requests?
2. How many reads in 24 hrs for a standard limits quota can firestore perform, after which it starts rejecting read requests?

Answer (score 1):

There are no broad limits like this.  As long as you're willing to pay for your reads and writes, you can effectively read and write as much as you want, given that you're within the other specific [documented limits](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas).  There is a limit to the rate of writes to a single document that you should be aware of, but nothing applying to writes spread across the entire database.

If you're asking about the daily limits on the free payment plan, they are also documented on that page.

Comment: i suspect when im doing a `batch.commit()` some records are dropping.

Comment: some records are showing up, some are not in firestore

Comment: You might want to ask a new question where you show a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates the problem.  You might just be doing something wrong.  Without seeing code, it's impossible to know.